# new Neo4jGraphQL({ typeDefs, driver }) causes Unknown directive error

Tags: neo4j, graphql, grandstack

I am trying to create a new GRANDstack application. The database already exists, so I've used the "infer-schema.js" script, to generate the gql schema. When I run the api server, I get the following error:

```
Error: Unknown directive "@relation".
13:42:38 api | Unknown directive "@relation".
```

This is on a fresh GRANDstack project - with the following untouched index.js:

```
const driver = neo4j.driver(
  process.env.NEO4J_URI || 'bolt://localhost:7687',
  neo4j.auth.basic(
    process.env.NEO4J_USER || 'neo4j',
    process.env.NEO4J_PASSWORD || 'neo4j'
  )
)

/*
 * Create an executable GraphQL schema object from GraphQL type definitions
 * including autogenerated queries and mutations.
 * Read more in the docs:
 * https://neo4j.com/docs/graphql-manual/current/
 */

const neoSchema = new Neo4jGraphQL({ typeDefs, driver })
```

With the schema:

```
type Incredient {
   _id: ID!
   name: String!
   recipes: [Recipe] @relation(name: "HAS", direction: IN)
}

type Product {
   _id: ID!
   name: String!
   has_offer: [Offer] @relation(name: "HAS_OFFER", direction: OUT)
   HAS_OFFER_rel: [HAS_OFFER]
   has_quantity: [Quantity] @relation(name: "HAS_QUANTITY", direction: OUT)
   HAS_QUANTITY_rel: [HAS_QUANTITY]
}

type Offer {
   _id: ID!
   newPrice: Float!
   normalPrice: Float!
   products: [Product] @relation(name: "HAS_OFFER", direction: IN)
}

type Quantity {
   _id: ID!
   name: String!
   products: [Product] @relation(name: "HAS_QUANTITY", direction: IN)
}

type Recipe {
   _id: ID!
   name: String!
   has: [Incredient] @relation(name: "HAS", direction: OUT)
   HAS_rel: [HAS]
}

type HAS @relation(name: "HAS") {
  from: Recipe!
  to: Incredient!
  amount: Float!
  unit: String!
}

type HAS_OFFER @relation(name: "HAS_OFFER") {
  from: Product!
  to: Offer!
  discount: Float!
}

type HAS_QUANTITY @relation(name: "HAS_QUANTITY") {
  from: Product!
  to: Quantity!
  quantity: Float!
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use infer schema for `@neo4j/graphql`(The official Neo4j GraphQL lib) and it's only to be used with the deprecated `neo4j-graphql-js`. You are trying to put a `neo4j-graphql-js` compatible schema into `@neo4j/graphql`. You should change `@relation` to `@relationship` and for relationship properties please refer to [this](https://neo4j.com/docs/graphql-manual/2.0/type-definitions/basics/#_relationship_properties).

Comment: Thank you. I just finished the GRANDstack book, and it is a bit sad, that it is already out of date.

Comment: Sorry about that, there are plans to update the book.